# Connect distinct id's to multiple names having same id

Tags: mysql, regex, excel, libreoffice-calc

Heey all,

I'm having difficulties with a large set of data.
I have one libreoffice calc sheet (excel sheet) with around 13k records.
2 Columns: Artist - Song

I want these into a mysql database so i've created 2 tables: `Artists`, `Songs`
With a foreign key in `Songs` to `Artists` so a Song records needs to have a valid `artist_id`.
I've inserted all the artists correctly being around 5k different artists.
This table works for what i want to do with it so that's no problem.

The problem is how would i connect the id of the artists to the song which is in the 2nd column of my sheet.
I want this so i'm able to create 12k insert queries and paste them right into phpmyadmin.

Any tips, regexes, other solutions?

EDIT

My excel sheet:

```
Artists     Songs              Artist (distinct)    Artist_id
Abba        mamma mia          abba                    1
Abba        waterloo           greenday                2
Greenday    american idiot
```

My output needs to be:

```
INSERT INTO Songs Values (1, "mamma mia");
INSERT INTO Songs Values (1, "waterloo");
INSERT INTO Songs Values (2, "american idiot");
```

The list of artists (distinct) and artist_id differs in length of Songs. That's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your `songs` table has fields `artist_id | song`. You could just use a formula to make your `INSERT` statement (Assuming your data starts in Row 1):

```
="INSERT INTO songs (artist_id, song) VALUES (" & Vlookup(A1, C:D, 2, false) & ",'" & B1 & "');"
```

We use a `vlookup()` formula to grab the `artist_id` for the `artist` in `A1` (Assuming that your `Artist (distinct) | Artist_Id` columns are `C:D` in this same sheet.

Then just copy that down to row 12000 and you're set.

In the event that your `song` in excel has a single quote in it, you could either escape those out, or replace them with nothing.

Escape:

```
="INSERT INTO songs (artist_id, song) VALUES (" & Vlookup(A1, C:D, 2, false) & ",'" & SUBSTITUTE(B1, "'", "\'") & "');"
```

Remove:

```
="INSERT INTO songs (artist_id, song) VALUES (" & Vlookup(A1, C:D, 2, false) & ",'" & SUBSTITUTE(B1, "'", "") & "');"
```

Comment: This isn't possible too bad. I have copied a list of artists in column A which had duplicate values as for each Song (which is in column B) the artist is listed again.
So i've extracted the duplicates and create a new row with distinct values of Artists leaving me with 5k rows of artists still 12k rows of songs. How would one connect those?

Comment: I'm confused.. You have a worksheet with `Artist | Song`. Is that that `Artist` in this example isn't the `Artist ID` but rather the `Artist Name`, but for the `INSERT` you need the `ID`? If that is the case, then extract your `Artist` table into a new tab from MySQL and then do a vlookup so you have `Artist_ID | Song` in two columns next to each other, then generate your `INSERT` statement like above. At some point, you will need to have `Artist_ID` and `Song` in the same row in your spreadsheet so you can insert them.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a `vlookup()` to grab the `id` for the `artist name`